# Display button libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm a beginner on LibGDX, and we currently work in group of 4 to make a Checkers game. It's a project for school.
We blocked to make the movement of pawns but it's not the problem. 
We have an architecture MVC.
On the game screen, we have a board game with pawns. We can not display a pawn, while on other screens it was easy.
I can make it appear but on the game board but it is not clickable. When I add

`stage.getViewport ().update (width, height, true)`

the button appears outside of the game board but not clickable and the game board is zoomed.

Here is a [link](https://gyazo.com/7b0cbee0429d681630fda0b6cb9e1d93) of the various classes

The problem is on the class `GameScreen`. When I click on play which is located on class `JouerIA` or `JouerJoueur`, I do a `setScreen(GameScreen)`.

So I paste here only `GameScreen` and `GameRenderer`. If you need more code to help me, I can paste more.

Here is the code without my different additions of buttons.

**GameScreen.java**

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private GameRenderer renderer;
public static String couleur1, couleur2, nom1, nom2;
Stage stage;
Skin skinneon;
OrthographicCamera camera;
TextButton menu;


@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    this.renderer.render(delta);

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);

}

@Override
public void show() {
    Plateau plateau;
    ControlPlateau controller;

    Assets.loadGame();

    plateau = new Plateau();
    plateau.ajoutPions();
    controller = new ControlPlateau(plateau);

    this.renderer = new GameRenderer(plateau, controller);
    this.renderer.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


}

@Override
public void hide() {
    this.renderer.dispose();
    Assets.disposeGame();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

}
```

**GameRenderer.java**

```
public class GameRenderer implements Renderer {

    private final Stage stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(10, 10));
    private Table hud;

    protected ControlPlateau controller;


    public GameRenderer(Plateau plateau, ControlPlateau controller) {



    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);
    this.stage.addActor(plateau);
    this.controller = controller;



        /*addListener(new InputListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(InputEvent event) {
               controller.tap();
            }
        });*/
        }

        @Override
        public void render(float delta) {
         Plateau plateau = new Plateau();

         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.3f, .3f, .4f, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         this.stage.draw();
         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new ControlPlateau(plateau)));
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        this.stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
        Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        this.stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The short answer is that you are reseting the input processor several times, so it doesn't get input from the stage. `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()` can only handle one input processor at a time. If you need to collect input from multiple sources, you want to create an `[InputMultiplexer][1]` class, give it all your input processors (i.e. stage, GestureDetector, etc.), then pass the `InputMultiplexer` to `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor()`- you can find more on the [libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputmultiplexer).

Now if you will permit me to critique your form, there are a few other things you may want to consider:

First: I'm a fair-weather MVC fan, but I would propose that you may save yourself some headaches if you think of your GameScreen.java class as your View (after all, a screen is a view)- you can then put your rendering code into the Screen's render() method and avoid creating a separate GameRenderer class. In my games, I have all my setup code in the Controller (think app controller, not gamepad controller or keyboard controller), and then each Screen gets a reference to the Controller and Model.

Second: In your renderer (should you choose to keep it), you'll want to avoid instantiating new objects in your render method. In the code you have above:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
  Plateau plateau = new Plateau();

  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.3f, .3f, .4f, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  this.stage.draw();
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new ControlPlateau(plateau)));
}
```

This will create a new `Plateau` object, a new `GextureDetector`, and a new `ControlPlateau` object every time render() is called- potentially 60 times a second! I strongly recommend moving these lines of code into a show() method so that your instantiation is only done once.

Hopefully that helps- let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  !
Maybe if we have time(because we are really late), i will modify what you criticized.
I have another question. If i choose to keep the renderer, i have to put the button with the InputMultiplexer in the renderer or in the GameScreen?

Comment: Almost- you put the button in the stage, and the stage in the InputMultiplexer. You would do this mapping in GameScreen.

Comment: it does not work. :'(
I'm sorry I'm French and not very good on libgdx.

If it's easier, I can send you my code directly, so you can tell me and explain the problem.

Comment: I tried again and here is what I get:
The game without modification:[link](https://gyazo.com/c8708c886c911b2f570054455fb90290)
The game with inputMultplexer: [link](https://gyazo.com/f3258887af4f66bc1ddfcd5bb5d70b0a)
We have the button but can not click on it and the checkerboard is bigger

Comment: The InputMultiplexer alone won't change how things are rendered- it must be one of the other changes you made. Is your code online somewhere? I'm not sure StackOverflow was really intended for this type of discussion.

Comment: I do not know where I could put it online.
If not, can I join you where to discuss more easily?
If I can get a boost, I will be very happy because we are stuck on our project for this problem ...
Certainly our code is not good, but for now everything works except that.

Comment: If this is code you can share, github.com is usually a good place. That or you can update the question with your code to reflect the actual problem, and I can edit my answer.

Comment: I upload my code in another account github because the first was on a github of our University.
Here the code :  [GitHub](https://github.com/MaximeBrl/Checkers)
The code is not very good but it works for now.

Comment: I'll take a look. I also did a writeup of MVC recently that you might find helpful in the meantime: http://otter.tech/an-mvc-guide-for-libgdx/

Comment: Thanks for the link, i put it in favorites

Comment: Sorry it's still me, but I've listened to your advice on github and it still does not work. I have this : 
[link](https://gyazo.com/d6265db045f0c433768e91e395030d08).  I'm lost...

Comment: When I run it locally it looks fine. Let's move the discussion to the github repo.

Comment: I left a comment on github